# Android: Alert dialogs for API 15 compatible for API grater than 8

Tags: android, dialog, android-fragments, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, alerts

I noticed that since I changed the build target to 4.0 i got a lot of warning. Almost all of them where referred to the showDialog / hideDialog used for all my alerts inside my app that are now deprecated.
I've seen Google introduced the Fragments also for this...but they are compatible from API 11 and greater.
My app has got the minSDK to 8...so it should work properly also on Android 2.3.3.
Any chance I can menage to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use the android support package in order to get access to DialogFragments in API 8

Support package info and how to obtain it can be found here [Android Support Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html)